# How to send a message from a website to an MQTT broker that does not support Websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket, tcp, mqtt, paho

I am very new to web development and I am doing a project where I am required to send a message from my own website to Thingstream which is a MQTT broker. I tried to use a Javascript library called MQTT Paho to send a message to the broker but the library uses WebSocket which is not supported by Thingstream. The broker only supports TCP. So I now intend to use Websockify which is a library that serves as a proxy to convert a WebSocket connection to TCP. However it is not clear to me how I would use Websockify to accomplish this. I have not been able to find sufficient documentation on how to use the library. Is it possible that someone can point out some useful documentation? Or perhaps an alternative method to do this task?

Comment: this might help https://barkingbogart.wordpress.com/tag/websockify/

Answer (score 0):

Find and using REST API:

```
Client -> REST API -> MQTT Broker -> MQTT Stream -> Client
```

Like [EMQ X REST API publish-message](https://docs.emqx.io/broker/latest/en/rest.html#publish-message)